# passing integers as parameter in drupal menu

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-routes

I'm using drupal 6

Suppose I have

```
  $items['path/yo'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'callback_function',
    'page arguments' => array(1),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

It will instead pass in the part of the path that is in the 1-th position (in this case it will pass 'yo') into the callback_function function...

But what if I'm actually TRYING to pass in the integer 1 into the function? How would I do that without casting it as string first and then reconverting to integer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $items['path/yo'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'callback_function',
    'page arguments' => array("1"),
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  );
```

See Wolfe's answer as well. If you enter (int) 1, it will be arg(1). Enter strings to be passed to the page callback as-is.

Answer (score 1):

php type conversion is very well done, you have to be careful with type casting however especially with 0 and 1 as they can be strings, numbers or booleans.

You can use type checks in your conditionals (such as === !==).  In your current example it isn't a string first it's a number.  It would pass 1 into callback_function.

```
function callback_function($args) {
print_r($args);
}
```

Will give you the arguments passed.  In this case `$args[0]` would be the number 1.  You shouldn't have to worry if it's a number or a string in 99% of cases because if you use it as a number php will convert it to a number and if you use it as a string php will treat it as a string.  Just be careful with conditional statements and be sure to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

For example to see if it is the number 1:

```
if(1 === $args[0]) echo "Numbah one!";
```

Will only print "Numbah one!" if it's a number type and the number 1.  You can typecast it if you like with

```
(int)$args[0];
(string)$args[0];
(boolean)$args[0];
```

respectively.

You might also check out this article:
http://drupal.org/node/1473458